# How to get the second item form a list of tuples and then compare it to the given number in the python shell

Tags: python, list, tuples

So have a list of tuples. Like so:

```
p1 = ("Name1", 14, 2005)
p2 = ("Name2", 21, 1998)
p3 = ("Name3", 18, 2001)
```

It has a name, persons age and the year they were born.

I put them together like so into a new list:

```
listPeople = [p1, p2, p3]
```

I have function Older that asks for the listPeople i just made and some number for age, lets say 15:

```
olderPerson = Older(listPeople, 15)
```

I cant figure out how should I compare the given age 15 to the listPeople and return only the people that are older than 15. Like so:

```
[('Name2', 18, 2001), ('Name3', 21, 1998)]
```

Right now i have this:

```
def Older(listOfPeople, age):
    newList = []
    ageInList = [lis[1] for lis in listOfPeople] #gives me all the age numbers

    if age > ageInList :
        newList.append(listOfPeople)
    return newList
```

I keep getting this error

```
if height > heightInList:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

I kind of know what it means but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

comes from age being a number and ageInList being a list (the list of all ages).

Aivar's answer shows a way that's more "Pythonic", i.e. uses a way well-suited to the Python language. The "list comprehension" he uses will take each record, where a record is for example ("Name1", 14, 2005), and only retain the records where the second element is above 15 (record[1] is the second element). The remaining records are automatically joined into a new list.

For the learning experience, your function could be changed like this:

```
def Older(listOfPeople, age):
    newList = []
    for record in listOfPeople:
        if record[1] > age:
            newList.append(record)
    return newList
```

Once you understand how this works, you can move on to list comprehensions to see Aivar's solution does the same thing, only with fewer words.

Comment: I would add to this excellent explanation that list comprehension is not only fewer word but also faster. List comprehension doesn't need to load the append attribute of the list and call it as a function at each iteration (not that it matters here).

Answer (score 1):

Isin't list comprehension simpler ('give me record for every record in list which has second item larger than 15'):

```
>>> lst = [("Name1", 14, 2005), ("Name2", 21, 1998), ("Name3", 18, 2001)]       
>>> [record for record in lst if record[1] > 15] 
[('Name2', 21, 1998), ('Name3', 18, 2001)]
```